# Vuetify - Change breakpoint sizes

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, breakpoints

I'm looking for change in Vuetify JS breakpoints, original looking as:

> Extra small   xs  Small to large phone    < 600px
>
> Small sm  Small to medium tablet  600px > < 960px
>
> Medium    md  Large tablet to laptop  960px > < 1264px*
>
> Large lg  Desktop 1264px > < 1904px*
>
> Extra large   xl  4k and ultra-wide   > 1904px*

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#usage

And I need to change Large Lg Desktop to 1366, how to make it?
this should allow me to use vuetify classes for break points like this **$vuetify.breakpoint.**

```
{
  // Breakpoints
  xs: boolean
  sm: boolean
  md: boolean
  lg: boolean
  xl: boolean

  // Conditionals
  xsOnly: boolean
  smOnly: boolean
  smAndDown: boolean
  smAndUp: boolean
  mdOnly: boolean
  mdAndDown: boolean
  mdAndUp: boolean
  lgOnly: boolean
  lgAndDown: boolean
  lgAndUp: boolean
  xlOnly: boolean

  // true if screen width < mobileBreakpoint
  mobile: boolean
  mobileBreakpoint: number

  // Current breakpoint name (e.g. 'md')
  name: string

  // Dimensions
  height: number
  width: number

  // Thresholds
  // Configurable through options
  {
    xs: number
    sm: number
    md: number
    lg: number
  }

  // Scrollbar
  scrollBarWidth: number
}
```

Please help me, because I don't know how to change it, and I don't want to create own breakpoint system by using Vuetify...

Answer (score 2):

you can read this part of the vuetify documentation, it has a good and complete example on how to modify grid-breakpoints:

[modify vuetify breakpoints](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#thresholds)

in your case you may have:

```
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

export default new Vuetify({
  breakpoint: {
    thresholds: {
      xs: 600,
      sm: 960,
      md: 1366,
      lg: 1904,
    },
  },
})
```

also you might need to implement these changes in css helper classes which there is tips to do it in the link provided above.